# How to get document field in variable for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to get document field in variable for mongodb

This code is not work:

```
db.Conversation.find().forEach(function(item)
{

    var _message = db.Message.find({ ConversationId : item._id.toString(), IsAgent : true }).sort({ SendDate: 1 }).limit(1);
    if(_message._id != null)
    {
           item.FirstAgentMessageId = _message._id.toString();
           item.FirstAgentMessageDate = _message.SendDate;
           db.Conversation.save(item);        
    } 
})
```

Thanx

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting, can you show that through the edit?

Comment: hi @chridam your code is return error : TypeError: db.Message.findOne({ConversationId:item._id.toString(), IsAgent:true}) has no properties (shell):4

Comment: i want to work with field of document. for example print(_message.ConversationId)

Comment: Change that to `var _message = db.Message.find({ ConversationId : item._id.toString(), IsAgent : true }).sort({ SendDate: 1 }).limit(1).toArray()[0]` since `findOne()` is not a cursor and hence does not have the `sort()` method, my apologies should have noted the typo.

Comment: Thank you @chridam it's worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successful code:

```
db.Conversation.find().forEach(function(item)
{

    var _message = db.Message.find({ ConversationId : item._id.str, IsAgent : true }).sort({ SendDate: 1 }).limit(1).toArray()[0]

    if(isObject(_message))
    {
           item.FirstAgentMessageId = _message._id.str
           item.FirstAgentMessageDate = _message.SendDate;
           db.Conversation.save(item);        
    }    
})
```